# split a string using a word delimiter in sas

Tags: string, sas

I'm looking for a way to split a very long string using this delimiter : `'| '`

The scan function doesn't seem to accept word delimiter so if I do

```
scan(string,3,'| ')
```

it will split at every `|` and space
instead of at every `'| '` like I need.

In the documentation I don't see any modifier allowing this. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000214639.htm

Comment: I just got an idea: use transwrd to replace `| ` by `_` and then use scan

Comment: Remove the space from your delimiter in the scan function, and it should work fine. If you get an extra space use strip or trim to remove leading spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out by myself

use `tranwrd` to replace `'| '` by `'_'`

```
newstring=tranwrd(string,'| ','_');
```

and then I can use the scan function normally

```
xxx=scan(newstringstring,3,'_');
```

Comment: You might want to consider a somewhat more obscure replacement string.  'FF'X

Comment: good Idea, I found out _ was already in the string and I switched to %, but will try your idea

Answer (score 3):

INFILE has DLMSTR when combined with infile magic can do exactly what you need.  Your transwrd idea should work well.

[image]

```
data test;
   input string $50.;
   cards4;
This|is | pipe space| delmimited
This| is| too I believe
;;;;
   run;
data test2;
   infile cards missover dlmstr='| ';
   if _n_ eq 1 then input @;
   array w[5] $64;
   do while(not eof);
      set test end=eof;
      _infile_ = string;
      input @1 w[*] @;
      output;
      end; 
   stop;
   cards;
Necessary evil
   run;
```